# Group array objects by two elements and sum values (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, reduce

I have the following case:

I have an array consisting of all the appointments of the currently logged in user, like this:

```
 this.appointments = [  
{ 
 CreatedBy: "bob",
 Description: "smthng",
 EndTime: "2020-06-01T17:00:00.000Z",
 EndTimezone: null,
 Id: 3,
 IsAllDay: false,
 Client: "Steven",
 Location: "smthng",
 RecurrenceRule: "FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;COUNT=5;",
 StartTime: "2020-06-01T09:00:00.000Z",
 StartTimezone: null,
 Subject: "smthng",
 km: 88,
 week: 23,
 _id: "5ecc6f4a08c79c6328974699"
}, 
{ 
 CreatedBy: "bob",
 Description: "smthng",
 EndTime: "2020-06-08T10:30:00.000Z",
 EndTimezone: null,
 Id: 4,
 IsAllDay: false,
 Client: "Steven",
 Location: "smthng",
 RecurrenceRule: null,
 StartTime: "2020-06-08T10:00:00.000Z",
 StartTimezone: null,
 Subject: "smthng"  ,
 km: 88,
 week: 24,
 _id: "5ed450d299d5303bd0338a7f"
}
  ]
```

What I ultimately want to do is group the array by Client per Week. So accumulate all the time and `km` of the appointments (using dayjs library) of one week per client. This is the `.reduce` function I have now which groups the array only by Client but not yet per week:

```
this.appointments.reduce(function (res, value) {
  let diff = dayjs(value.EndTime).diff(dayjs(value.StartTime), "hour",true) % 60;
  let count;

  if(value.RecurrenceRule != null) {
    count =  parseInt(value.RecurrenceRule.split("COUNT=")[1]);
    if(value.RecurrenceException){
    if(value.RecurrenceException.match(/,/g) ) {
      if(value.RecurrenceException.match(/,/g).length == 0) {
        console.log(value.RecurrenceException.match(/,/g).length);
        count = count -1;
      }
    } else if(value.RecurrenceException && value.RecurrenceException.match(/,/g).length == 1) {
      console.log(value.RecurrenceException.match(/,/g).length);      
      count = count -2;
    } else if(value.RecurrenceException && value.RecurrenceException.match(/,/g).length == 2) {
      console.log(value.RecurrenceException.match(/,/g).length);
      count = count -3;
    } else
    if(value.RecurrenceException && value.RecurrenceException.match(/,/g).length == 3) {
       count = count -4;
    };
  }
  }
  else if(value.RecurrenceRule == null) {
       count = 1;
  }
  if (!res[value.Client]) {
    res[value.Client] = {

      week: value.week,
      km: value.km * count,
      Client: value.Client,
      count: count,
      difference: diff * count
    };
    result.push(res[value.Client]);


  } else {
    res[value.Client].km += value.km * count;
    res[value.Client].difference += diff * count;
  }

  return res;
}, {});
```

How do I go about this situation? 
the output now is that instead of creating two rows (week 23 & 24), it sums all the appointments of Steven in week 23 which is incorrect because 0.5 hour took place in another week.

```
{Client: "Steven"
count: 5
difference: 40.5
km: 528
week: 23}
```

So the ideal output is:

```
{
Client: "Steven"
count: 5
difference: 40
km: 440
week: 23 
},

{
Client: "Steven"
count: 1
difference: 0.5
km: 88
week: 24
}
```

You can have rows with the same week number as long as the Client differs.

I hope i made it clear and if you need more context, please mention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on @ajai's answer (and using his input first for comparison), hopefully giving you what you need (and using reduce).

```js
const data = [  
  { 
   CreatedBy: "bob",
   Description: "smthng",
   EndTime: "2020-06-01T17:00:00.000Z",
   EndTimezone: null,
   Id: 3,
   IsAllDay: false,
   Client: "Steven",
   Location: "smthng",
   RecurrenceRule: "FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;COUNT=5;",
   StartTime: "2020-06-01T09:00:00.000Z",
   StartTimezone: null,
   Subject: "smthng",
   km: 88,
   week: 23,
   _id: "5ecc6f4a08c79c6328974699"
  }, 
  { 
   CreatedBy: "bob",
   Description: "smthng",
   EndTime: "2020-06-08T10:30:00.000Z",
   EndTimezone: null,
   Id: 4,
   IsAllDay: false,
   Client: "Steven",
   Location: "smthng",
   RecurrenceRule: null,
   StartTime: "2020-06-08T10:00:00.000Z",
   StartTimezone: null,
   Subject: "smthng"  ,
   km: 88,
   week: 24,
   _id: "5ed450d299d5303bd0338a7f"
  },
  { 
   CreatedBy: "bob",
   Description: "smthng",
   EndTime: "2020-06-01T17:00:00.000Z",
   EndTimezone: null,
   Id: 3,
   IsAllDay: false,
   Client: "Steven",
   Location: "smthng",
   RecurrenceRule: "FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;COUNT=5;",
   StartTime: "2020-06-01T09:00:00.000Z",
   StartTimezone: null,
   Subject: "smthng",
   km: 40,
   week: 23,
   _id: "5ecc6f4a08c79c6328974699"
  },
  { 
   CreatedBy: "bob",
   Description: "smtng",
   EndTime: "2020-06-01T17:00:00.000Z",
   EndTimezone: null,
   Id: 3,
   IsAllDay: false,
   Client: "ajai",
   Location: "smthng",
   RecurrenceRule: "FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;COUNT=5;",
   StartTime: "2020-06-01T09:00:00.000Z",
   StartTimezone: null,
   Subject: "smthng",
   km: 88,
   week: 23,
   _id: "5ecc6f4a08c79c6328974699"
  }
]    
  

const result = Object.values(data.reduce((aggObj, item) => {
  const stringID = `${item.Client}_${item.week}`;
  const diff = (new Date(item.EndTime) - new Date(item.StartTime))/(1000*60*60);
  const RecurrenceObj = item.RecurrenceRule ?
    item.RecurrenceRule.split(";").map(a => {
      //console.log(a)
      return a.split("=") || ["_", null];          
    }).reduce((aggObj, [key,val]) => {
      aggObj[key] = val;
      return aggObj;
    })
    : {COUNT: 1};
    
  if (aggObj[stringID]){
    aggObj[stringID].km += (item.km * RecurrenceObj.COUNT);
    aggObj[stringID].count += parseInt(RecurrenceObj.COUNT);
    aggObj[stringID].difference += (diff * RecurrenceObj.COUNT);
  }
  else {  
    aggObj[stringID] = {
      Client: item.Client,
      km: item.km * RecurrenceObj.COUNT,
      count: parseInt(RecurrenceObj.COUNT),
      difference: diff * RecurrenceObj.COUNT,
      week: item.week
    };
  }
  return aggObj;
}, {}));

/*
for(var i=0;i<=data.length-1;i++){
   let pos = result.findIndex(el=> `${el.Client}-${el.week}`==`${data[i].Client}-${data[i].week}`)
   if(pos==-1){
     result.push({Client: data[i]['Client'],count: 1,difference: 0,km: data[i]['km'],week: data[i]['week']})
   }else{
     result[pos]['count'] = result[pos]['count'] + 1;
     result[pos]['km'] = result[pos]['km'] + data[i]['km'];
   }
}
*/
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

OUTPUT:

```js
[
  {
    "Client": "Steven",
    "km": 640,
    "count": 10,
    "difference": 80,
    "week": 23
  },
  {
    "Client": "Steven",
    "km": 88,
    "count": 1,
    "difference": 0.5,
    "week": 24
  },
  {
    "Client": "ajai",
    "km": 440,
    "count": 5,
    "difference": 40,
    "week": 23
  }
]
```

Now with your exact input:

```js
const data = [  
  { 
   CreatedBy: "bob",
   Description: "smthng",
   EndTime: "2020-06-01T17:00:00.000Z",
   EndTimezone: null,
   Id: 3,
   IsAllDay: false,
   Client: "Steven",
   Location: "smthng",
   RecurrenceRule: "FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;COUNT=5;",
   StartTime: "2020-06-01T09:00:00.000Z",
   StartTimezone: null,
   Subject: "smthng",
   km: 88,
   week: 23,
   _id: "5ecc6f4a08c79c6328974699"
  }, 
  { 
   CreatedBy: "bob",
   Description: "smthng",
   EndTime: "2020-06-08T10:30:00.000Z",
   EndTimezone: null,
   Id: 4,
   IsAllDay: false,
   Client: "Steven",
   Location: "smthng",
   RecurrenceRule: null,
   StartTime: "2020-06-08T10:00:00.000Z",
   StartTimezone: null,
   Subject: "smthng"  ,
   km: 88,
   week: 24,
   _id: "5ed450d299d5303bd0338a7f"
  }
]    
  

const result = Object.values(data.reduce((aggObj, item) => {
  const stringID = `${item.Client}_${item.week}`;
  const diff = (new Date(item.EndTime) - new Date(item.StartTime))/(1000*60*60);
  const RecurrenceObj = item.RecurrenceRule ?
    item.RecurrenceRule.split(";").map(a => {
      //console.log(a)
      return a.split("=") || ["_", null];
    }).reduce((aggObj, [key,val]) => {
      aggObj[key] = val;
      return aggObj;
    })
    : {COUNT: 1};
    
  if (aggObj[stringID]){
    aggObj[stringID].km += (item.km * RecurrenceObj.COUNT);
    aggObj[stringID].count += parseInt(RecurrenceObj.COUNT);
    aggObj[stringID].difference += (diff * RecurrenceObj.COUNT);
  }
  else {  
    aggObj[stringID] = {
      Client: item.Client,
      km: item.km * RecurrenceObj.COUNT,
      count: parseInt(RecurrenceObj.COUNT),
      difference: diff * RecurrenceObj.COUNT,
      week: item.week
    };
  }
  return aggObj;
}, {}));

/*
for(var i=0;i<=data.length-1;i++){
   let pos = result.findIndex(el=> `${el.Client}-${el.week}`==`${data[i].Client}-${data[i].week}`)
   if(pos==-1){
     result.push({Client: data[i]['Client'],count: 1,difference: 0,km: data[i]['km'],week: data[i]['week']})
   }else{
     result[pos]['count'] = result[pos]['count'] + 1;
     result[pos]['km'] = result[pos]['km'] + data[i]['km'];
   }
}
*/
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

OUTPUT:

```js
[
  {
    "Client": "Steven",
    "km": 440,
    "count": 5,
    "difference": 40,
    "week": 23
  },
  {
    "Client": "Steven",
    "km": 88,
    "count": 1,
    "difference": 0.5,
    "week": 24
  }
]
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. However I get this error msg:  `TS2339: Property 'fromEntries' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'. Should I update my IDE settings to es2019 with the risk of the app not working on all browsers,are there any other alternatives which do not require a higher typescript version?

Comment: IE is the only major browser you wouldn't be supporting - https://caniuse.com/#search=fromEntries - I can post a work-around / polyfill for that. I edited my answer to use reduce, instead, is that ok?

Comment: I swapped Object.fromEntries for Reduce, which is supported since IE 9 - https://caniuse.com/#search=array%20reduce - is that enough browser support for you?

Comment: If you are using typeScript, you should also be able to use the "latest-and-greatest" without worries, as you can transpile typeScript down to es2015/ES6 or down to ES3 if you want to. But yes, perhaps your typeScript version is one which did not have Object.fromEntries included in its compiler/transpiler

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is what your expectation
and I'm not sure what to do with difference just explain me if this is not satisfied.

```js
var data = [  
{ 
 CreatedBy: "bob",
 Description: "smthng",
 EndTime: "2020-06-01T17:00:00.000Z",
 EndTimezone: null,
 Id: 3,
 IsAllDay: false,
 Client: "Steven",
 Location: "smthng",
 RecurrenceRule: "FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;COUNT=5;",
 StartTime: "2020-06-01T09:00:00.000Z",
 StartTimezone: null,
 Subject: "smthng",
 km: 88,
 week: 23,
 _id: "5ecc6f4a08c79c6328974699"
}, 
{ 
 CreatedBy: "bob",
 Description: "smthng",
 EndTime: "2020-06-08T10:30:00.000Z",
 EndTimezone: null,
 Id: 4,
 IsAllDay: false,
 Client: "Steven",
 Location: "smthng",
 RecurrenceRule: null,
 StartTime: "2020-06-08T10:00:00.000Z",
 StartTimezone: null,
 Subject: "smthng"  ,
 km: 88,
 week: 24,
 _id: "5ed450d299d5303bd0338a7f"
},
{ 
 CreatedBy: "bob",
 Description: "smthng",
 EndTime: "2020-06-01T17:00:00.000Z",
 EndTimezone: null,
 Id: 3,
 IsAllDay: false,
 Client: "Steven",
 Location: "smthng",
 RecurrenceRule: "FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;COUNT=5;",
 StartTime: "2020-06-01T09:00:00.000Z",
 StartTimezone: null,
 Subject: "smthng",
 km: 40,
 week: 23,
 _id: "5ecc6f4a08c79c6328974699"
},
{ 
 CreatedBy: "bob",
 Description: "smtng",
 EndTime: "2020-06-01T17:00:00.000Z",
 EndTimezone: null,
 Id: 3,
 IsAllDay: false,
 Client: "ajai",
 Location: "smthng",
 RecurrenceRule: "FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;COUNT=5;",
 StartTime: "2020-06-01T09:00:00.000Z",
 StartTimezone: null,
 Subject: "smthng",
 km: 88,
 week: 23,
 _id: "5ecc6f4a08c79c6328974699"
}
  ]    
let result = []
for(var i=0;i<=data.length-1;i++){
   let pos = result.findIndex(el=> `${el.Client}-${el.week}`==`${data[i].Client}-${data[i].week}`)
   if(pos==-1){
     result.push({Client: data[i]['Client'],count: 1,difference: 0,km: data[i]['km'],week: data[i]['week']})
   }else{
     result[pos]['count'] = result[pos]['count'] + 1;
     result[pos]['km'] = result[pos]['km'] + data[i]['km'];
   }
}
console.log(result)
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. The 'difference' variable is the difference in time between the 'StartTime' and 'EndTime' properties. So I want to sum these differences for the particular client in that week. I hope i cleared it up for you